# jquery: get value of custom attribute in drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple JQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $( ".translanguage" ).change(function() {
      var value = $(this).attr("langid");
      alert(value);
  });
});
```

and i have html code.

```
<select name="translanguage" class="translanguage">
  <option value="0">Please Select Language</option>
  <option class="transoption" value="1" langid="1">Urdu</option>
  <option class="transoption" value="2" langid="2">English</option>
  <option class="transoption" value="3" langid="3">Arabic</option>
  <option class="transoption" value="4" langid="4">Sindhi</option>
</select>
```

When i run this program, it is giving undefined error in alert box. I need the value of langid as given in my option tage.

So what is the problem in my code. ?

Secondly what is the cause of undefined error in JQuery.

Thanks

Comment: You should add `data-`in front of your custom attributes: `data-langid="1"`. Then it's valid HTML5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside the change handler `this` refers to the `select` element, but the `langid` is in the selected `option` element. So you need to find the selected `option` and then call `.attr("langid")` on that element

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(".translanguage").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("langid");
        alert(value);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GjXfM/)

Answer (score 3):

This script will work for you.
See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sach1177/7vEwS/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".translanguage").change(function () {
        var value = $( "select option:selected" ).attr("langid");
        alert(value);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
      $( ".translanguage" ).change(function() {
          alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('langid'));
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// jquery wont find the attr of langid, change the langid to id in html.
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $( ".translanguage" ).change(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(value);
  });
});
```